# What is the best and most universal way to unzip an archive using php 5?

Tags: php, zip, unzip

I'm writing software that requires the user to have php 5, but nothing else in the way of extra apache modules, etc.

Is there a vanilla php5 method for unzipping an archive?

I found this:

https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ziparchive-extractto.php

But can everyone using php 5 use this? No extra modules necessary?

Comment: "In order to use these functions you must compile PHP with zip support by using the --enable-zip  configure option. "
http://nz2.php.net/manual/en/zip.installation.php

Comment: @Rob - Right on the money. +1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the documentation (as Rob pointed out), PHP needs to be compiled with the --enable-zip option for linux or the php_zip.dll needs to be enabled for windows. That said, no extra apache modules are needed. And I would venture to say that almost all PHP installations have this enabled already. To the point where you can *almost* depend on it being there. That said, the safest possible bet would, of course, be to not assume anything. So at the end of the day, it is a judgement call.

https://www.php.net/manual/en/zip.installation.php